# how to show a certain number of child groups

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an `ExpandableListView`, the count of `child groups` can vary since they are dynamically created. I need the *first 3* `child groups` to be **always** expanded by default. When the user clicks on a `main group`, the rest of the `child groups` will be expanded (I attached a figure illustrating the **default state** of an `ExpandableListView` I need to achieve). I haven't found any methods for the `ExpandableListView` which would allow to achieve that.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Did you start a bounty without ask a real question? Please, ask your question clearly.

Comment: I thought I have expressed myself clearly enough and attached a figure. An `ExpandableListView` consists of main and subgroups (or child groups). `expandGroup()` method will show all subgroups of a main group. I need to only show 3 subgroups of each main group.

Comment: How do you pass data to the adapter? Do you know the group and children counts beforehand?

Comment: groups - yes, always 3. Children - may vary, depends on the number of Elements in the XML response I get from server. For passing data, I use `List<String>` for groups and `HashMap<String, List<MyClass>>`for children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a similar idea as @Pr38y but didn't find the time to code it (until now). Still kudos to him/her. This ExpandableList *prevents* full collapse of a group. It's done by only switching the childCount for each group, based on a boolean (`isGroupExpanded`).

Demo myClass:

```
public class myClass {
    int id;
    String name;
    public myClass(int id, String str) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = str;
    }
}
```

Activity (sorry for the humongous HashMap initialization):

```
package com.example.explvhack;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Simon on 2014 Jul 8.
 */

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ExpandableListView expList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expList);

        // Create the adapter with 3 groups
        final List<String> groups = new ArrayList<String>() {{add("Group1"); add("Group2"); add("Group3");}};
        final ExpLvAdapter expAdapter = new ExpLvAdapter(getBaseContext(), groups);

        // If group is not "expanded" it displays 3 children, else displays all
        // This listener, forces it to toggle between fake expanded and collapse states
        expList.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView dad, View v, int grpPosition, long id) {
                expAdapter.isGroupExpanded[grpPosition] = !expAdapter.isGroupExpanded[grpPosition];
                expAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                return true;
            }
        });

        expList.setAdapter(expAdapter);

        // Populate the groups
        HashMap<String, List<myClass>> newData =
                new HashMap<String, List<myClass>>() {
                    {
                        put(groups.get(0), new ArrayList<myClass>() {
                            {
                                add(new myClass(0, "Grp1Child1"));
                                add(new myClass(1, "Grp1Child2"));
                                add(new myClass(2, "Grp1Child3"));
                                add(new myClass(3, "Grp1Child4"));
                                add(new myClass(4, "Grp1Child5"));
                                add(new myClass(5, "Grp1Child6"));
                                add(new myClass(6, "Grp1Child7"));
                                add(new myClass(7, "Grp1Child8"));
                            }
                        });
                        put(groups.get(1), new ArrayList<myClass>() {
                            {
                                add(new myClass(0, "Grp2Child1"));
                                add(new myClass(1, "Grp2Child2"));
                                add(new myClass(2, "Grp2Child3"));
                                add(new myClass(3, "Grp2Child4"));
                            }
                        });
                        put(groups.get(2), new ArrayList<myClass>() {
                            {
                                add(new myClass(0, "Grp3Child1"));
                                add(new myClass(1, "Grp3Child2"));
                                add(new myClass(2, "Grp3Child3"));
                            }
                        });

                    }
                };
        expAdapter.putAll(newData);
        expAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // Keep the groups opened
        expList.expandGroup(0);
        expList.expandGroup(1);
        expList.expandGroup(2);
    }

}
```

And the custom adapter:

```
package com.example.explvhack;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Simon on 2014 Jul 8.
 */

public class ExpLvAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<String> groups;
    private HashMap<String, List<myClass>> children = new HashMap<String, List<myClass>>();
    public boolean[] isGroupExpanded = new boolean[] {false, false, false};

    public ExpLvAdapter(Context context, final List<String> groups) {
        this.context = context;
        this.groups = groups;
    }

    public void putAll(HashMap<String, List<myClass>> newData) {
        children.putAll(newData);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = new TextView(context);

        // (Re)Use the convertView
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView;
        textView.setPadding(60, 0, 30, 0);
        textView.setText(children.get(groups.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition).name);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        int childrenCount = (children.size() == 0) ? 0 : children.get(groups.get(groupPosition)).size();

        if (isGroupExpanded[groupPosition])
            return childrenCount;
        else
            return Math.min(3, childrenCount);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = new TextView(context);

        // (Re)Use the convertView
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView;
        textView.setText(groups.get(groupPosition));

        return textView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition){
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);

    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }
}
```

By the way I also removed the group indicator so there would be no confusion if it's open or not. I used `android:groupIndicator="@null"` in my `<ExpandableListView .../>`

Comment: thanks mate, this solution saved me from a lot of headache. Now I have to add an `ImageView` to the groups layout and use it instead of the `groupIndicator`, but that's not a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

duplicate your special child items as top-level items, styled to appear like child items. then when a top-level item is expanded for real, set the height of the fake child items to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Using normal linearlayout with listview could be a better approach. on click of title in the linearlayout you can fully pouplate the list of the listview adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged` and on next tap you can reduce the list to 3 elements.

Using `ExpandableListView` for the first time you can return 3 from `getChildCount()` and next time the size of the entire list. You can achieve this effect by either from `onGroupExpandListener` or from the `adapter` itself.